# BitmapFactory start-up issues with decodeResources and getResources

Tags: android, bitmapfactory, android-studio-2.2

As seen before by others, I'm also really new in the Android world. I used to program in Python and/or C++. Now I'm trying to learn how to make a nice Android app. I found a nice guide on this website: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

but Im stuck on the displaying a bitmap step. I cannot find anything about this on the Internet, nor on stackoverflow. In my code I have this part:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;   
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.test,options)
```

Whatever I do, or read on the internet, I cannot remove the following things:

1. `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` always has a red line under it saying: unexpected token. Also when I type "options", ther is no autocomplete.
2. `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.queen_heart,options)` says that decodeResource cannot resolve symbol.
3. `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.queen_heart,options)` says that getResources has an invalid method declaration
4. When I type BitmapFactory, I can only do "options" as autocomplete.

I use Android Studio 2.2.2

See below my whole code.

```
package com.example.sjaak.myfirstapp;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by sjaak on 22.12.16.
 */

public class PrepLoadImage {
    // Get the dimensions of the image.
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.test,options)
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;

    // Fit the image to the screen
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two statements which do not end on a `;`. That will not compile. Further you should -temporarily change `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.test,options)` (without `;`! to `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test, options);`. You will then see that the compiler complains about an unknown function `getResources()`.

Comment: Does `R.drawable.test` exist in the `drawable` folder?

Comment: `stuck on the displaying a bitmap step. I cannot find anything about this on the Internet, nor on stackoverflow`. Well you can find exactly your code again and again every day on stackoverflow. Every day. Day after day.

Comment: So your real problem is that `getResources()` is an unknown function. Not a member of yur class.

Comment: `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;`. Is red as you cannot put that code in the body of your class. Add a constructor member function where you can do that.

Comment: You are causing yourself a lot of trouble by trying to make a class out of this code. And the static member function can never work as the resource is not loaded then. Make it non static and add the constructor to let it work. Give the constructor a `Resources res` parameter which you initialize with `getResources() ` in the calling class.

Comment: Hi greenapps, 

Thank you for your answers. As noticed, I tome me some time (holidays, etc). It really helped. I have all the errors gone and I could build the app. Now, I can go to the next step. 

Have a nice holiday and a happy 2017!